# .htaccess GET parameters for friendly URL doesn't work

Tags: .htaccess, get

I'm looking to make my url's more seo friendly but I'm really having a hard time figuring out what the issue is because I've been trying to rewrite this url for 3 days now. No code doesn't seem to work.

So I have 3 url's:

```html
https://website.net/jobs/country.php?country=switzerland
https://website.net/jobs/state.php?country=switzerland&state=bern
https://website.net/jobs/state.php?country=switzerland&state=bern&city=17462
```

I want to get these:

```html
/jobs/switzerland 
/jobs/switzerland/bern/
/jobs/switzerland/bern/17462/
```

I just can't seem to understand what the problem is. This is my code for the first link, which obviously doesn't do anything:

```html
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^jobs/country/([0-9]*)/?$ /jobs/country.php?country=$1 [L, QSA]
```

Also this is part of a forum so there is existing rewrites, but I don't really know if they affect anything because even on a fresh htaccess I wasn't able to make it work:

```html
# Some hosts require RewriteBase to make RewriteRules work.
RewriteBase /

# Google SEO workaround for search.php highlights:
# Make this rule the first rewrite rule in your .htaccess!
RewriteRule ^([^&]*)&(.*)$ https://website.net/$1?$2 [L,QSA,R=301]


Options -MultiViews +FollowSymlinks -Indexes

#
# If mod_security is enabled, attempt to disable it.
# - Note, this will work on the majority of hosts but on
#   MediaTemple, it is known to cause random Internal Server
#   errors. For MediaTemple, please remove the block below
#
<IfModule mod_security.c>
    # Turn off mod_security filtering.
    SecFilterEngine Off

    # The below probably isn't needed, but better safe than sorry.
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

#
# MyBB "search engine friendly" URL rewrites
# - Note, for these to work with MyBB please make sure you have
#   the setting enabled in the Admin CP and you have this file
#   named .htaccess
#
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteRule ^jobs/country/([0-9]*)/?$    /jobs/country.php?country=$1    [L, QSA]

    RewriteRule ^forum-([0-9]+)\.html$ forumdisplay.php?fid=$1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^forum-([0-9]+)-page-([0-9]+)\.html$ forumdisplay.php?fid=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]

    RewriteRule ^thread-([0-9]+)\.html$ showthread.php?tid=$1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^thread-([0-9]+)-page-([0-9]+)\.html$ showthread.php?tid=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^thread-([0-9]+)-lastpost\.html$ showthread.php?tid=$1&action=lastpost [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^thread-([0-9]+)-nextnewest\.html$ showthread.php?tid=$1&action=nextnewest [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^thread-([0-9]+)-nextoldest\.html$ showthread.php?tid=$1&action=nextoldest [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^thread-([0-9]+)-newpost\.html$ showthread.php?tid=$1&action=newpost [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^thread-([0-9]+)-post-([0-9]+)\.html$ showthread.php?tid=$1&pid=$2 [L,QSA]

    RewriteRule ^post-([0-9]+)\.html$ showthread.php?pid=$1 [L,QSA]

    RewriteRule ^announcement-([0-9]+)\.html$ announcements.php?aid=$1 [L,QSA]

    RewriteRule ^user-([0-9]+)\.html$ member.php?action=profile&uid=$1 [L,QSA]

    RewriteRule ^calendar-([0-9]+)\.html$ calendar.php?calendar=$1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^calendar-([0-9]+)-year-([0-9]+)-month-([0-9]+)\.html$ calendar.php?calendar=$1&year=$2&month=$3 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^calendar-([0-9]+)-year-([0-9]+)-month-([0-9]+)-day-([0-9]+)\.html$ calendar.php?action=dayview&calendar=$1&year=$2&month=$3&day=$4 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^calendar-([0-9]+)-week-(n?[0-9]+)\.html$ calendar.php?action=weekview&calendar=$1&week=$2 [L,QSA]

    RewriteRule ^event-([0-9]+)\.html$ calendar.php?action=event&eid=$1 [L,QSA]

    <IfModule mod_env.c>
        SetEnv SEO_SUPPORT 1
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>

#
# If Apache is compiled with built in mod_deflade/GZIP support
# then GZIP Javascript, CSS, HTML and XML so they're sent to
# the client faster.
#
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css text/html application/xhtml+xml text/xml application/xml text/plain text/x-component application/javascript application/x-javascript application/rss+xml application/atom+xml application/json application/manifest+json application/x-web-app-manifest+json application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/font-sfnt application/font-woff application/font-woff2 image/svg+xml image/x-icon
</IfModule>

# Note: You are able to choose a different name in the Admin CP. If you've done that you need to change it here too
<Files "error.log">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
</Files>



# Some hosts require RewriteBase to make RewriteRules work.
RewriteBase /

# Google SEO workaround for search.php highlights:
# Make this rule the first rewrite rule in your .htaccess!
RewriteRule ^([^&]*)&(.*)$ https://website.net/$1?$2 [L,QSA,R=301]

# Google SEO 404:
ErrorDocument 404 /misc.php?google_seo_error=404

# Google SEO Sitemap:
RewriteRule ^sitemap\-([^./]+)\.xml$ misc.php?google_seo_sitemap=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

# Google SEO URL Forums:
RewriteRule ^Forum\-([^./]+)$ forumdisplay.php?google_seo_forum=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

# Google SEO URL Threads:
RewriteRule ^Thread\-([^./]+)$ showthread.php?google_seo_thread=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

# Google SEO URL Announcements:
RewriteRule ^Announcement\-([^./]+)$ announcements.php?google_seo_announcement=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

# Google SEO URL Users:
RewriteRule ^User\-([^./]+)$ member.php?action=profile&google_seo_user=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

# Google SEO URL Calendars:
RewriteRule ^Calendar\-([^./]+)$ calendar.php?google_seo_calendar=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

# Google SEO URL Events:
RewriteRule ^Event\-([^./]+)$ calendar.php?action=event&google_seo_event=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Thank you.

Comment: _"This is my code for the first link, which obviously doesn't do anything"_ - yes, that `^jobs/country/` does not match on `/jobs/switzerland`, is really pretty obvious ...

Comment: I'm just looking to add the 'country/' string before the actual country variable. I still don't know what's wrong about it.

Comment: You said you _wanted_ to use the URL `/jobs/switzerland` - that does not contain `country` anywhere. But the rule you created, would only match on URL paths starting with `/jobs/country/` - so that clearly doesn't fit together.

Comment: ok, I get it, you were talking about my url examples. I'm now at    RewriteRule ^jobs/([0-9]*)/?$    /jobs/country.php?country=$1    [L, QSA] but now /jobs/index.php simply redirects me to some random country.

Comment: Actually _redirects_ (where to then), or just _shows_ the content of some random country on the loaded page? And did you actually request `/jobs/index.php`, or just `/jobs/`? Because for `/jobs/index.php`, your pattern from that rule would not match to begin with.

Comment: yeah so /jobs/ shows the content to random country, jobs/index.php stays the same /jobs/country.php?country=switzerland also stays the same.

Comment: _"/jobs/country.php?country=switzerland also stays the same"_ - yes, but that _should_ stay the same - this is your _internal_ URL, that correctly passes the parameters to the script. Redirecting that somewhere else, would be counter-productive to what you want to achieve here in the first place. You _should_ be testing what happens when you request `/jobs/switzerland`

Comment: I get 404. So I want the /jobs/country.php?country=switzerland to redirect to /jobs/switzerland, I think we might be talking about different things or I probably just don't get it.

Comment: _Redirecting_ from `/jobs/country.php?country=switzerland` to the new "nice" URL is only necessary for URL that might not be under control - external sites having set a link to the former somewhere, or search engines having it indexed. But that is only the secondary aspect here - first of all, you need to implement the _other direction_ - the internal rewrite from `/jobs/switzerland` to `/jobs/country.php?country=switzerland`

Comment: Ok but my my php variables get posted to those url's, so they need to be internally like that. I don't really know. Can you just give me a working solution for one so  i can just adapt to the rest of them? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, _internally_. But on the _outside_, you want to use the "pretty" URLs. If you previously made your POST request to `/jobs/country.php?country=switzerland`, then you should now make it to `/jobs/switzerland` instead. Changing what the URLs you output into your HTML or JavaScript look like, is not mod_rewrite's job to begin with - that's _yours_.

Comment: Well if the php link to those how do i _get the variables?

Comment: The other rewrites for the forum seem to be the dame way i'm trying to do.

Comment: Those _are_ the other direction that I am talking about - rewrite internally, _from_ the pretty URL format, to the one using GET parameters in the URL. _"i'm trying to do"_ - well have you at least fixed the issue with `country` being a part of your pattern now?

Comment: I'm sorry, i just don't understand what you're saying. Thanks for the help.

Comment: The pattern `^jobs/country/([0-9]*)/?$` can never, not ever, match the URL path `/jobs/switzerland` - simply because the static text `country`, that your pattern _demands_ to come after the `jobs/` part, is not in there. So I am asking if you fixed that at least by now?

Answer (score -1):

I got chatGPT to answer it.
For people looking for a solution you can try to use mine or I guess just ask chatGPT.

```html
# Redirect /jobs/state.php?country=...&state=...&city=... to /jobs/.../.../...
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/jobs/state\.php\?country=([^&]+)&state=([^\s&]+)&city=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^jobs/state\.php$ /jobs/%1/%2/%3? [R=301,L,NE]

# Redirect /jobs/state.php?country=...&state=... to /jobs/.../...
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/jobs/state\.php\?country=([^&]+)&state=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^jobs/state\.php$ /jobs/%1/%2? [R=301,L,NE]

# Redirect /jobs/country.php?country=... to /jobs/...
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/jobs/country\.php\?country=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^jobs/country\.php$ /jobs/%1? [R=301,L]

# Rewrite /jobs/.../.../... to /jobs/state.php?country=...&state=...&city=...
RewriteRule ^jobs/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9%_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9%_-]+)$ /jobs/state.php?country=$1&state=$2&city=$3 [QSA,L,B,NE]

# Rewrite /jobs/.../... to /jobs/state.php?country=...&state=...
RewriteRule ^jobs/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9%_-]+)$ /jobs/state.php?country=$1&state=$2 [QSA,L,B,NE]

# Rewrite /jobs/... to /jobs/country.php?country=...
RewriteRule ^jobs/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /jobs/country.php?country=$1 [QSA,L]
```